# TFS Build vNext : Lot of itrace on codecoverage enable

Tags: tfs, code-coverage, intellitrace, vnext

On our build server, we have a space disk problem. After investigation, we found a lot of te.processhost.managed_xxx_xxx_xxx.itrace files in C:\Windows\Temp. It's take nearly 50Go.

There were created on a process building in TFS 2015 vNext, on the task Visual Studio Test but there are never delete automatically.

There were not created if we disable Codecoverage option (but we need this option of course).

How can we disable automaticaly creation of these files ? Or automaticaly delete these files in the process (without script) ? Any option ? Other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

From TFS 2015 Update 3 (upgrade your TFS if your version is lower than this Update 3), there is a task named [Delete files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/delete-files), you could add this task after Visual Studio Test task to delete the .itrace files.

Comment: I have create a PS script wich aims delete all itrace files in the Windows temp folder.  
I'm so surprise nobody have that behavior and we have this behavior on many servers in my company. Wrong setting perhaps.

Comment: I can't test it for now. I'll test as soon as possible.

Comment: Or you could simply try `Delete  files` task.

Comment: I can't test now. But it's the same solution that using PS for delete. It's not answer my question : Why I have this behavior. Your answer probably work but it's not complete. I can't validate as solution.

Comment: If you run build and test locally on your build agent machine, will you have this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with build agents of version 2.122.1, "Visual Studio Test 1.*" and TFS 2017 Update 3.

I worked around it with a scheduled run of the following PowerShell script:

```
get-childitem -Path $env:SystemRoot\Temp -Filter *.itrace | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).AddHours(-1)} | Foreach-Object { del $_.FullName }
```